# Include 3rd party jars in bundle

Tags: java, osgi, classloader

I'm trying to include 3rd party jar in my bundle. I'm following this tutorial http://www.aqute.biz/Blog/2007-02-19 , but in my Activator i get ClasNotFoundException while trying to refer to a class from that external jar.

My bundle jar directory structure:

```
-\MyBundle
  -\plugin.xml
  -\META-INF
    -\MANIFEST.MF
  -\org
    -\mybundle
      -\Activator.class
  -\3rdParty.jar
```

MANIFEST.MF looks like this:

```
...
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 3rdParty.jar
...
```

It's a part of Eclipse 3.5.1 RCP application.

Error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 3rd.party.proxy.ConfiguratorProxy
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at my.program.eclipse.core.ProcessEditorUploaderActivator.start(ProcessEditorUploaderActivator.java:111)
```

But when I'm invoking this.getClass().getResource("/3rdParty.jar") it works.

**Edit: problem solved**. I had to remove org.eclipse.core.runtime, org.eclipse.equinox.app and org.eclipse.osgi directories from my RCP app. Information about bundles classpath was cached.

Comment: Is `3rdparty.jar` one of the jars mentioned in you Bundle-ClassPath? Also, could you post the exact message (i.e., what class seems to be missing, and where do you expect it to come from?)

Comment: Yes, 3rdparty.jar is one of the jars mentioned in Bundle-ClassPath. I've made a correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it from Eclipse? If so, your thirdparty bundle should also be listed in your .classpath file. You should have a line like:

`<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/thirdparty.jar"/>`

(This should happen automatically when using the MANIFEST editor)

If you are exporting the plugin and running it some other way, you'll need a build.properties file, that should look something like:

```
source.. = src/ 
output.. = classes/ 
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
           .,\
           lib/thirdparty.jar
```

Comment: I'm exporting bundle to jar and load to my RCP app. There is the build.properties file in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- Is your 3rdParty.jar really inside the bundle jar? Open with Winzip and check.
- Is your Manifest.MF correct? Try putting all entries of the Bundle-ClassPath: on one line, no new lines: 
  Bundle-ClassPath: .,3rdParty.jar
- Where are you trying to access the classes from? The classes of the internal jar will be visible from the classes of MyBundle.jar, but they won't be visible from other bundles in the framework, unless you export the packages in the manifest!

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm trying to access external class by this.getClass().forName("3rd.party.proxy.ConfiguratorProxy").

Comment: 1. Yes, it's inside. 2. Manifest seems correct. I've tried milion of configurations. 3. I'm trying to access external class from start() method in my Activator class. I found out that I can access classes of another 3rdParty2.jar even without specyfying it directly in my Bundle-ClassPath. But for the first jar it doesn't work.